# Excel Conditional Formatting for expired dates

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, rules, conditional-formatting

I have training that is due every year for a group of 30 people. I want to find a way on excel to make the cells change colors. Lets say the training was on 5/13/2015 I want to find a way where that cell would automatically change from green (valid) to yellow (a month before expiration) and red (expired). This training is valid for only one year. So i would like the cell to change yellow for 4/13/2016 so a month before that training date is not valid. (these dates are examples and not everyone has the same training date).

Answer (score 1):

The same principle as @Abe but if to allow for leap years and that months vary in length while also taking heed of the fact that there are 30 people involved (say with training dates in A1 to A30) then perhaps select A1:A30 and fill (standard) green then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=A1<DATE(YEAR(Now())-1,MONTH(Now()),DAY(Now()))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Fill, red, OK, OK, and New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
 =A1<DATE(YEAR(Now())-1,MONTH(Now())+1,DAY(Now()))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, Fill, yellow, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Conditional Formatting in Excel.

Here is a step by step example using unit values instead of dates , but the idea is the same: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RQnTGlM57g

The video also shows written instructions here: http://www.contextures.com/xlCondFormat01.html

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting, the formula for the expired training would be:

```
=NOW()-$A$1>365
```

The formula for the expiring training would be:

```
=NOW()-$A$1>335
```

A1 being an example of the cell to format.

Then change the rules to format the text color. The rules should be in this order. See screenshot:[image: Screenshot]